# Cabecera fija tabla html

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap, tablas

estoy intentando mantener la cabecera (th) de una tabla html fija para que no se pierda de vista al explorar el contenido de la tabla, he utilizado algunos ejemplos y soluciones que he visto por aquí, y por allí, y no consigo que funcione..

el CSS que estoy probando es este:

```
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tfoot{
  width: 97%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tfoot,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead > tr> th,
.table-fixed tfoot > tr> td{
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Las referencias:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href = " https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css " rel = "stylesheet" /> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"/>
```

la tabla se genera en php:

```
echo "<table class='table table-fixed' id='table' border = 1  cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 2>"; 

echo "<thead >
      <tr>"."<th align='left' width='500'>CIUDAD"."</th>"
<th>....
<th>....
<th>....
"<th >Total.</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>"

Aquí los datos de la tabla.

"</tbody></table>"
```

El resultado es el mismo, no hay cambios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna idea de porqué no funciona???

Gracias..

Después de mucho investigar y pensar (lo cual ya me va costando), una solución que puede valer es:

```
thead tr th { 
            
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            
        }


tfoot  {

position:sticky;
bottom: 0px;
background-color:silver;
z-index:15;

}
```

aunque pierde los bordes de la celda y no se porqué...

Comment: en ningun lado veo position fixed o sticky, probaste con eso?

Comment: si, he probado ambos pero el comportamiento es el mismo..